# Google is indexing image filenames on my revolution slider

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a slight problem, I recently launched a website with a image slider (revolution slider), I have some images on it and google is crawling the image names and showing it in my search results, is there a way to hide those image names from google so it stops?  I'm not sure if this will get flagged for "off topic" but I thought I'd give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `alt` and/or `title` attributes to those images, or give them more meaningful names.
It will take a while for Google to reindex it.

Comment: Oh okay, well I launched it last night and google already indexed it.  I'll try that!  Thanks :)